# How to store firebase analytics data offline for more than 72 hours?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase for analytics and I have enabled firebase persistent storage which helps to send the analytics events to firebase when the device comes online but the limitation is it only sends 72 hours data to Firebase analytics.

I want firebase to get at least offline analytics data of the last 10 days.

Can I achieve this by storing this analytics event in core data when the device is offline and send this event to firebase when the device is connected to the internet?

Or is there any alternative way to achieve this?

I only want to send the event name and timestamp of the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do *something* to store the events locally, but it'll be finicky and error prone.

When storing the events yourself and then submitting them when the device is online, I see many potential problems. Off the top of my head:

1. There is no API to track the lifecycle of Firebase's built-in purging of analytics event. So you have a decent chance of events being logged twice.
2. You can't backdate the events, so any events you fire upon reconnecting are going to show up as having happened then.
3. You're likely going to miss events that Firebase logs automatically. You could probably compensate, but at that point you're almost building your own Analytics solution.

Honestly that is some of the potential problems, and you're likely to encounter many more. I'd seriously consider if the effort is really worth it, or if you'd be better off picking another solution.

Some solutions that come to mind:

1. Log your own events directly to BigQuery. Then merge then with Firebase's exported Analytics events, and deduplicate the results.
2. Pick an analytics provider whose API meets your requirements directly.